# Need example of OAuth 2.0 access in PHP to Google Shopping API using ONLY CURL

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0

I have a PHP-7 application which needs to access the Google Shopping API *(OAuth2.0 ...)* from the back-end servers.  In other words, it must use CURL.  I am looking for as complete an example as possible – from any source.

I do not want to use Google's code which first of all doesn't seem to use CURL and second of all seems to involve over 7,000 new PHP source-files.

Many APIs seem to reference `$_GET[]` as though the requesting agent was itself "a web page."  In this case, it is not:  the requests are being made using CURL, and must be so.

Comment: I did not down vote your question but I am guessing those who did (and were rude and did not leave a comment) did so because it was merely a "do this for me" without showing any effort of your own.

Comment: Also, someone was kind enough to give an answer below.  Did it work?  Did you even try it?  If so, please be kind enough to up vote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
        $data = array("post" => $vars, "post2" => $vars2);
        $data_string = json_encode($data);
        $ch = curl_init('https://endpoint.com/');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $oauth_key,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
        );
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
```